# Запретить вставку строки, если уже есть 3 строки с таким значением

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id SERIAL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    active bool
);
```

Мне нужно вставить в таблицу новую строку, но при вставке убедиться, что вместе с моей строкой в таблице не будет больше 3 строк с active=true для одного user_id. Я не единственный кто может в этот момент выполнить запрос, т.е. параллельная запись возможна. Создать индекс не получится, потому что у других пользователей должна быть возможность вставить больше 3 строк. Пока на ум приходит только блокировка таблицы на запись (EXCLUSIVE). Я сторонник того, что блокировку нужно применять только в том случае, когда нет никакого другого выхода, почти всегда находится такой выход. Есть способ лучше блокировки?

Comment: Триггер решает такую задачу.

Comment: @Akina можно минимальный пример? Не совсем понимаю как это использовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В postgresql есть два пути решения данной проблемы. Первый способ - использование уровня изоляции транзакций [serializable](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/transaction-iso#xact-serializable). На нем postgresql гарантирует, что две одновременные транзакции будут вести себя так, как будто они выполнялись строго последовательно. Цена этому, возможность аварийного завершения одной из транзакций, в случае если БД обнаружит *вероятность* взаимного влияния. По этой причине ваше приложение должно быть готово повторить транзакцию заново, в случае если произошла ошибка сериализации. Порядок действий:

1. Начать транзакцию `begin isolation level serializable;`
2. Получить текущее количество записей для данного пользователя обычным select ... where user_id=X and active=true
3. В зависимости от количества принять решение о вставке или возможно о модификации записей
4. `commit`
5. В случае если при commit произошла ошибка серализации выполнить действия заново, с п.1

Внимание: выполнение п 5 обязательно, возможны ложные ошибки сериализации произошедшие не по причине наличия 3х подходящих записей. Например могут возникать ошибки при работе в 2х транзакций с близкими id пользователей, так как будут использованы предикатные блокировки страниц индекса, которые затрагиваются чтением и записью в транзакции. А на одной странице индекса могут располагаться данные по нескольким пользователям.

Второй способ - использовать [рекомендательные блокировки](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/explicit-locking#advisory-locks) с помощью одной из [специализированных функций](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/functions-admin#functions-advisory-locks). Порядок действий:

1. Начать транзакцию
2. Выполнить например pg_advisory_xact_lock(UserID) для взятия исключительной блокировки по данному пользователю в пределах транзакции.
3. Получить количество подходящих записей
4. При необходимости выполнить insert
5. `commit`

Comment: Я что-то не понимаю. Я запустил тразнакцию и сделал `SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(id) FROM upload_sessions WHERE user_id=1;` В консоль вывелось что залочена одна строка. Оставив транзакцию открытой я открыл ещё одно подключение с БД. В новом подключении попытался обновить эту строку и вставить новую строку с таким же user_id и то и то мне удалось. Почему так? Разве эти действия не должны были ожидать закрытие транзакции в другом подключении?

Comment: @Inventor pg_advisory_xact_lock не блокирует запись самой таблицы. эти блокировки можно сказать блокируют переданное им значение. Вот есть у вас id=25 функция сделает блокировку с числом 25. Если другая транзакция так же выполнит в это время pg_advisory_xact_lock(25) то она будет ждать завершения первой. А к самой таблице где вы что то делаете с этим 25 они никакого отношения не имеют и конечно любые другие транзакции которые не вызывают pg_advisory_xact_lock ничего не заметят

Comment: Хм, спасибо, я понял, думаю тогда это не подходит. Это не совсем надёжно. Во-первых сложно гарантировать что все запросы которые работают с этой таблицей будут выполнять эту блокировку. Во-вторых можно сделать `DELETE` по id а не user_id. И тогда оно отработает неправильно. Я конечно могу получить user_id перед удалением строки и выполнить блокировку. Но так думаю запутаться легко будет. Наверное это удобно когда с таблицей работают только из одного участка кода. Вернусь к своему варианту - блокировкам на уровне таблицы

Comment: @Inventor Много мест работающих с таблицей на запись говорит о проблемах с архитектурой приложения. В идеале запись вообще вся должна оказаться в одном модуле. Если задача расписана в вопросе в полном объеме, то проблемными могут быть только вставка и модификация поля active и то только в направлении false->true. (Если предположить, что модификация поля user_id вообще запрещена). А эти 2 момента вполне можно проконтролировать на уровне триггеров